# KDB: how to compare strings?

Tags: kdb

I have a column of type C. How do I compare the value to the previous value in the same column? I did `col1 like prev col1` but it returns a `Correction hint: length` error. I also created another column `newCol: prev col1` but still cannot perform the comparison. I also tried with `=` and no luck. How can I do this?
a sample data:

```
col1
Paris
London
London
New York
Singapore
Ha Noi
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you use the `prior` keyword?

```
q)t
col1       
-----------
"Paris"    
"London"   
"London"   
"Ney York" 
"Singapore"
"Ha Noi"   
q)select (~) prior col1 from t
col1
----
0   
0   
1   
0   
0   
0
```

When comparing strings, if they are the same length it will check that each character in each slot of the array is the same, and return a list of booleans to tell you where the strings are the same. If the strings are two different lengths, you will get a length error. If you want to test if two strings are the exact same thing, you can use `~`, which will work regardless of the length of the string and give you a single boolean telling you if they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use each prior:https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-prior

With match: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/comparison/#match

```
    q)tab:([]col1:("Paris";"London";"London";"New York"))
    q)select col1,compare:(~':)col1 from tab
    col1       compare
    ------------------
    "Paris"    0
    "London"   0
    "London"   1
    "New York" 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `like'` instead of `like`, because you are comparing not to single value, but to list.

```
update comparison: col1 like' prev col1 from 
  ([]col1:("Paris";"London";"London";"New York";"Singapore";"Ha Noi"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is essentially the same as Matthews and jomahony's answers, the `differ` keyword can arguably make it easier to read/understand:

```
q)select not differ col1 from ([]col1:("Paris";"London";"London";"New York"))
col1
----
0
0
1
0
```